# Symfony 3: How to implement password update?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to implement password update. So therefore I'll ask for:

1) Current password
2) New password
3) Repeated new password

My form builder in UserProfileForm looks like this:

```
class UserProfileForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('plainPassword', RepeatedType::class, array(
                'type' => PasswordType::class,
                'first_options' => array(
                    'label'       => 'Password',
                    'constraints' => array(new NotBlank(array(
                        'groups'  => array(
                            'updatePasswordChecked',
                        )
                    ))),
                ),
                'second_options' => array(
                    'label'       => 'Repeat password',
                    'constraints' => array(new NotBlank(array(
                        'groups'  => array(
                            'updatePasswordChecked',
                        )
                    ))),
                ),
                'invalid_message' => 'Passwords don\'t match!',
            ))
            ->add('oldPassword', PasswordType::class)
            ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Save'));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class'            => 'AppBundle\Entity\User',
            'validation_groups' => array('update'),

        ));
    }
}
```

Within User entity I've added $oldPassword:

```
/**
* @SecurityAssert\UserPassword(
*     message = "Wrong value for your current password",
*     groups = {"updatePasswordChecked"}
* )
*/
private $oldPassword;
```

Controller where I'm trying to update password:

```
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    public function detailAction(Request $request)
    {
        $user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

        $form = $this->createForm(UserProfileForm::class, $user);
        $form->handleRequest($request);


        if ($form->isSubmitted())
        {
            if ($form->isValid())
            {
                dump('valid');
                // do whatever is needed to update the password
            }
        }

        return $this->render('pages/profile.html.twig', array('profileForm' => $form->createView()));
    }
}
```

After submitting the form with the right old password, I'm getting an error that the old password is wrong, and the system logs me automatically out.

In Symfony profiler I can see that the right data is being submitted.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should check out how the fosuser bundle does it and that will give you a clear idea. Plus inside the controller you do not need to do `$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();` just `$this->getUser()` should be enough to get the current user

Comment: It seems like you forget to encrypt your plain old password before validating it.